# TCL Partial String Match

Tags: string, tcl

Hoping a kind tcl guru can help me.

I have this string match, which works, to match an email address.

```
if { [string match "joe.blogs@thisdomain.com" $emailFromAddress] } {
   set sendAutoReply 0
```

This works perfectly, however I want the string to ignore joe.blogs@ and only match on the thisdomain.com.
The reasoning behind this, I don't want to auto reply to any one from a specific domain i.e. thisdomain.com and since that could be 1000's of email addresses (which I won't know) my thinking is to just match on the domain name.

Any thoughts on how best to do this, in a nice simple way?

Comment: The `string match` commands supports simple wildcards. Anything that doesn't work with that because more complex matching is required has to be done with `regexp` (or an actual parser; there are tools for making them in Tcllib).

Answer (score 1):

Use a wildcard in the pattern instead of an explicit username?

```
if { [string match "*@thisdomain.com" $emailFromAddress] } {
   set sendAutoReply 0
}
```

Comment: @MrJam [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)